# How to change text UILabel in swift code?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and I am trying to understand UILabel text property

Based on what I have read, my understanding is that I can replace text with any String . So I did

[image]

The text property is "read-only" , is there a way I can change text label by hardcoding in swift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a value like this in the declaration section of the class.

Since you're working with a UIViewController, you'll want to go to the `viewDidLoad()` method and put `self.Food.text = "Burger"` there.

For example:

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Food: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.Food.text = "Burger"
    }
}
```

The `viewDidLoad()` method is called by the system when (coincidentally enough) the view is first loaded. After the view has loaded, you are free to make any edits to any of the objects on the screen. `viewDidLoad` will be where you will want to perform the majority of the setting up of your view.

Answer (score 2):

I am not in front of my computer to verify this, but I don't think you need to mark it as "self"

Just `Food.text = "Burger"`

Additionally. It is common for you to put variables with the first letter as lower case with each other words first letter being upper case

For example.

```
var firstWord = "Traditionally the best way to code"
```

Capital first letter first word is traditionally used for classes.

Example

```
Class NewClass = "Blah Blah"
```

Answer (score 1):

100% programatically would be like this. This both creates the label and the string.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
label.text = "Burger"
self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```